# How to configure Xcode 9.1 with Gitlab?

Tags: ios, xcode, gitlab

I have created a repo. on BitBucket. then I clone that repo to the Gitlab.now i want to connect Gitlab's repo to the Xcode(9.1).So I can directly push, pull and do all the git stuff from Xcode.

is there any way to do that?

thanks!!!

Comment: please see this. https://www.raywenderlich.com/153084/use-git-source-control-xcode-9

Answer (score 0):

The best way really is to follow the instructions GitHub gives you:

First, go the correct directory

```
cd <directory of your Xcode project>
```

It sound like you've already got a local Git project from Xcode. If that's true, skip this code block.

```
git init .
git add .
git commit -s
<type in a commit message>
```

Last, push into your repository. The following is copied directly from my own github account, after I created a new "test" repo. Change the "dhalperi/test" part. Hope its help you.